# Can I pick up UK train ticket with debit card for closed account?

Tags: uk, trains, tickets, payment-cards

I just bought train tickets on redspottedhanky.com with a US card (I'm moving back to the UK in September), but I realised I've booked it with my US Debit card. I'd planned to close by account before leaving, but now am worried I wont be able to get my tickets from the machine in the UK.

Do I need to keep my account open for this?

Comment: Like other SE sites, we expect users to show what they've done to find an answer. So: have you asked at redspottedhanky.com? Their contact page is here: http://www.redspottedhanky.com/contact-us/contact-us-about-booking/

Comment: I've contacted RSH but no reply yet. In any case, this is an issue outside their scope, I believe, as it's more to do with the self-service machines at UK train stations.

Comment: You can use any card to retrieve train tickets from an automated machine in the UK, it doesn't need to be the one the booking was made with.  I used to travel a lot and the office would book tickets for me using a company card, I would retrieve them using my own card and a booking reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For almost all UK train tickets you seem to be able to collect your tickets with any card that the system recognize as a card to pay with. That includes several cards which are not payment cards at all.  See the answers to these two older questions, [one,](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58606/why-does-collecting-a-uk-train-ticket-require-you-to-insert-a-card) [two.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24291/can-you-collect-uk-train-tickets-from-machines-with-a-non-chip-card)

As it does not always works, it will be better to bring the card you booked with, even when it is no longer valid as a payment card. (Some train companies which use your payment card for ID purposes, like the German DB, tell you to bring the card you paid with even when it is no longer valid, as it is still recognized.)

In case the machine does not print your tickets you can still get them from the ticket window, officially you should have the same 'proofs' but the ticket window staff can use their own judgement and they can visually check a card where the machine can only use the in-build features. Having the same card, even when no longer valid, with your story of having closed the account, should be enough.

In short, bring booking reference and the actual card you paid with, which does not need to be valid anymore, as well as a card which will work in the machines, like your credit card or a new debit card. One of them should work, if not, ask at the ticket window.