# How does Eurostar segregate Brussels-bound and London-bound passengers from the Netherlands?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, paperwork, eurostar

There are now direct trains Amsterdam-London calling at Rotterdam and Brussels, and one can book a ticket Amsterdam/Rotterdam -> Brussels on it.

Given Schengen, how are Brussels-bound and London-bound passengers segregated?

This used to be a major, dangerous hole in the Schengen and UK borders, with trains Brussels-London calling at Lille, but was solved by confining Lille-bound passengers to the far rear coach of the train.

So how is it handled for trains from Amsterdam? The Dutch border control didn't give me a clear answer, and Eurostar is currently taking around a month to respond to emails.

Comment: The answer to the Brussels-Lille question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/82911/33703

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have not been able to take that train yet, (it was cancelled when I was booked on it, September,) but I think they do it that same way, allow Brussels and Lille passengers in one part of the train and UK passengers in the other part.
The platform in Amsterdam has a barrier, so they can keep one part of the train in a restricted zone, while the rest is open to 'all' passengers. I think they build it like that in Rotterdam as well.
In Brussels you clear the part of the train the Brussels passengers used and do not open the doors of the cars the Amsterdam and Rotterdam passengers use.
You can then allow new passengers in at Brussels, repeat in Lille if needed and you can now go through the tunnel.

I was going to post this as a comment but it became too much an answer, so posted as an answer even though I have not seen it happen.

Comment: Confirned to be correct!

Comment: It turns out there is no barrier on the platform in Amsterdam, but I guess they employ people to act as a barrier when the Eurostar train is on the platform. I have only been there when I was actually taking that train but never near the dividing line (if there even was one.)

Comment: The "barrier" is the Eurostar check-in facility which is on platform 15. So the train extends to both sides of that facility

Comment: I mean there is no barrier between the stairs and the Eurostar train when it is on the platform. I have been able to enter the platform (from the far end) at the time the Eurostar train drove off, past me.